# Is it possible to measure ground water level by using coconut?

Tags: geography

In South India, there are people who claim that they can measure the underground water level by using the coconut.

They will hold coconut in their palm and walk on the site. Near the water source the coconut moves upwards, defying the gravitational pull and thus mark the spot for digging bore well.

I have witnessed this and the place they marked got abundance of water after digging.

I wanted to know is it true that we can measure water level by using coconut or is it just a phoney trick. If it is true, how it can happen? Is there any scientific explanation for this?

Comment: I think that the scientific accepted explanation is that the dowser (is that the name?) recognizes signs of underground water in the surface, such as the type, growth and color of vegetation; and that underground water is much more common than most people think.

Comment: Where'd you get the coconuts? This is a temperate zone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the United States and much of Europe (and perhaps other places), the tradition is to use a stick for the same purpose.  In english, it is called a Dowsing Rod [(wikipedia link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowsing).  As far as I know, studies have shown that the results of Dowsing are no better than random chance.

However, I have met more than one person here in the US who swear that it's an effective technique :)

Comment: And as far as I know: there is no scientific explanation how exactly (as through which force) this shall work - the change in gravitational force on a coconut is clearly much to small for a human to sense, I doubt it would be measurable even with high-tech equipment...

Comment: And why would you use a coconut in the first place? I mean, other than the obvious possibility to make hoove sounds while pretending to ride away afterwards.